# Parameter to pass to get nearest road name or building name in HERE reverse geocode

Tags: here-api

for this lat and long =23.759871&lng=90.411991, i should get this out put 
North 27m,Siddik School,Madhubag, Dhaka Bangladesh

but when i am using api like this 
https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=23.759871%2C90.411991%2C1000&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=10&additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel%2CpostalCode&gen=9&app_id=xxxxxK&app_code=xxxx

it does not give the above out put, i get bellow
which parameter do i need to set to get the avove out put which is accurate ?

```
Address": {
                                "Label": "Dhaka, Bangladesh",
                                "Country": "BGD",
                                "State": "Dhaka",
                                "County": "Dhaka",
                                "City": "Dhaka",
                                "District": "Madhubag",
                                "AdditionalData": [
```

Comment: Hi, are you looking for address of the school? Then you should use places search. please check  https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/what-is.html

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, and Sorry for the delay as i was away, what I understand is your API does not give Exact Road name from the lat/lon, it gives the nearest location from the given lat/lon ( please correct me if i am wrong)  , with the attached API call, it gives me only nearest road but not the current road name,  but i need a nearest place name (in any category ) i look at the places api, here i need to spcify the category, is there any way to construct it so that it give me any nearest  place from the given lat/lon ?

Answer (score 0):

> invalid
>   credentials for xxxxxK

From the above error it seems that there is problem with the **app_id** parameter

You need to enter the correct app_id and app_code.

Also to get the correct app_id and app_code you can refer this

[How to get App ID and App Code for Here Maps](https://www.iwdagency.com/help/dealer-store-locator/how-to-get-app-id-and-app-code-for-here-maps)

Comment: those xxx i removed original app code, the problem is, I am looking for a nearest place ( any category) from the given lat/lon , as I understand here does not give exact road name from the given lat/lon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to create a new app id and code

When I try with a point on N124 road near toulouse Toulouse 43.601144, 1.279583 https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode

I don't get 'N124' the name of the road, and does Here has an identification system for section of roads like "osm_id" in Osm openstreet map system